# Android Studio 2.1 freezes when Logcat starts

Tags: android-studio

Sometimes, when I use Android Studio 2.1 and build and deploy the app, Android Studio freezes, and looks like a *still image*.
It can't responde to useful user interaction: (*though* it does not change into *Not responding* state)

I can click:

- Close - it does nothing
- Minimize - it minimizes the IDE

The last build message is this:

> **Activating Logcat Tool window**

[image]

If I kill *adb.exe*, nothing changes and adb.exe appears again after a few seconds.

What could I do about this? Should I report that?

Comment: Experiencing the same problem here. I guess it's a bug of Android Studio. Why not just report the issue?

Comment: Same here. Android Studio 2.1.3

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, found out that this was caused by the enormous filter in logcat and solved it in the following way:

0. Have your Android Studio closed.
1. Go to the {root project folder}/.idea/workspace.xml
2. Find the TOOL_WINDOW_CUSTOM_FILTER key and set its value to the empty string.
3. Start the Android studio again.

Answer (score -2):

1) Open TakManager and kill Android Studio.
2) Re Open Android Studio.
3) Go to File, invalidate and Restart Android Studio.
4) Click on invalidate and Restart.